# How specific a unique color to each row item of listview on android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, getview

I had a listview that fill from content of database, for that I wrote a custom arrayadapter. I need every item in listview have a unique color as ribbon on one side. same as down part of following photo
[Flat Design](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdesignmodo.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F05%2FSquirrel-Settings.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdesignmodo.com%2Fflat-design-principles%2F&h=450&w=600&tbnid=tTfHwDX7xNWC2M%3A&zoom=1&docid=H8pE2_bJ0md-vM&ei=QravU9LbDsewPMrvgaAL&tbm=isch&ved=0CCUQMygHMAc&iact=rc&uact=3&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20&dur=716)

but my list have 20 items therefore scrolled. when I scrolled down and up the position of color get change. This is happened while it just enter to switch/case just for a first time when rowItem.getIds() is equals to 0 or 1 or 2. I just see the the first System.out.println with the "UP" string every times that scrolled, but the others(Other system.out.println without "UP") just one times.for clearance I attached my codes:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
Context context;
String fontType = "";
float fontSize;
int resourceID;

int colour = 0;
int dif = 0;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    resourceID = resourceId;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    View img;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    System.out.println("UP " + rowItem.getIds() + "  " + rowItem.getTitle());

    Typeface type;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.indexitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textOfRowWithImage);

        if (colour == 0)
            switch (rowItem.getIds()) {
            case 0:
                holder.img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
                holder.img.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(52, 73, 92));
                System.out.println(rowItem.getIds() + "  "
                        + rowItem.getTitle());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
                holder.img.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(244, 179, 80));
                System.out.println(rowItem.getIds() + "  "
                        + rowItem.getTitle());
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
                holder.img.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(92, 151, 191));
                System.out.println(rowItem.getIds() + "  "
                        + rowItem.getTitle());
                break;

            }
        else
            holder.img.setBackgroundColor(colour);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



    holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(fontSize);

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}



public void setSidebarColor(int i) {
    colour = i;
}
   }
```

the RowItemClass:

```
public class RowItem {
    private String title;
    private String desc;
    int numbers;

    public RowItem(String title, int i) {
        this.title = title;
        this.numbers = i;
    }

    public RowItem(String title, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Integer getIds() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (desc != null)
            return title + "\n " + desc;
        else
            return title;
    }

}
```

and in main class I put rowItem as follow

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < poemtype.size(); i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(poemtype.get(i), i);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
```

I used position before used rowItem.getIds() but that was have same result, I tried  "rowItem.getIds()" because I understand position depend on the move up and down get change and is the position of item that show on device.

Comment: where you changed value of `colour`? you need put that if (set color) outside of if else of checking `convertView`

Comment: Check listview position & set color

Comment: I used colour!= 0 for colored all the part with the same color and change value of that on public void setSidebarColor(int i)  method.

Comment: put `if (colour == 0)
            switch (rowItem.getIds()) {` out side of if statement, and put that after `else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`

Comment: You set the color value depend on the `rowItem.getIds()`.such as `Color(rowItem.getIds()%255,34,34)`,something like this.

Comment: No guys none of them doesn't work for me. when I scrolled down and up colored more rows. Maybe I must change the position of that but I don't have any idea to where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is due to **view recycling** by `ListView`. Whenever items are scrolled out of the screen, their views are placed in a recycler, and are passed again to the Adapter's `getView()`, as the `convertView` parameter. This is a performance optimization.

A consequence of this is that you must "completely reset" any view properties that you customize in `getView()`. Otherwise, the properties from the recycled view will be shown.

In short, you should change the background color of `img` *always*, not only when `convertView == null`. Something like this:

```
if (convertView == null)
{
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.indexitem_row, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
    // ... assign other holder fields.
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

int color = getColorForRow(position);
holder.img.setBackgroundColor(color);
// continue ...
```